# How do I search for specific text in a string using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am using [this](https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/imdb-extensive-dataset?select=IMDb%20movies.csv) dataset to try and make a dynamic bubble graph but I came across an issue. When I search for the genre eg Western it searches for exactly that string. The problem is that `'dataset_by_year["genre"]'` holds genres with multiple genres (e.g. western, comedy, action), which is not matched.

```
for genre in genres:
    dataset_by_year = BubbleGV[BubbleGV["year"] == year1]
    dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[
        dataset_by_year["genre"] == genre]
```

All I want to do is to search for the genre within the multiple genres and match the string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So how exactly are those stored? Is it a list of strings, a string containing comma-separated values, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry didn't check with your full data try this, it might work:

```py
dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year["genre"].str.contains(genre)]
```